# Mutliple threads accessing synchronised and unsynchronised methods on same object

Tags: java, multithreading

Suppose there is a class Test which has one synchronized method m1, and one non synchronized method m2, and an instance of Test, say obj.Two threads T1 and T2, try to access methods related to instance obj. 
What happens when T1 invokes obj.m1(synchronized method), and before it completes m1 execution, T2 invoked obj.m2(non-synchronized).
Will T2 have to wait?

I was asked this question in an interview.

**My Answer:** T2 will continue to execute without any wait. T2 is accessing non-synchronized method, hence it does not need any lock.

The interviewer did not seem to agree with my answer, though when I asked him back about the correctness of my answer, he did not provide any input.

Please help me understand if I am missing something.

**P.S.** I have tried a test program already, and I see that my understanding is right. I am just wondering if there is any special scenario where this would not work as I explained to the interviewer.

Comment: Why don't you just test it? It would have been faster than writing your question.

Comment: You get blocking where two threads try to hold the same lock at the same time. Different locks or no locks have no effect. This is regardless of which method is called on what object.

Comment: Perhaps the interviewer was looking for more, or thought that an answer given by another candidate was better without knowing specifically what was better better about it.

Comment: @JB Nizet I already tested that :) From what I see my answer was correct. I am just wondering if there is any special scenario that I am missing

Comment: Yes, your answer is correct. If the interviewer thought otherwise, then he/she's wrong. If he/she would have liked more details, then he/she should have asked for them. Maybe you just misinterpreted his behavior.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Well, You answer sure was correct, but i guess the small reply didn't made the interviewer happy or maybe he had higher expectations and wanted a very clear explanation for his question.

I wont be writing any code to answer your question, but i will state two points highlighting the basics of `multi-threading` in java.

> 1) Each object has only one lock.
>
> 2) If two threads say T1 and T2 are trying to execute synchronized instance methods on the same object, then the thread which obtains the lock first will be able to execute the synchronized method and the other thread T2 will have to wait until T1 completes its execution or enters into blocking/waiting state for some handful number of reasons. In other words, No Thread T2 can not enter ANY (I repeat ANY) `synchronized` method for an object "obj" if Thread T1 already has a lock for the same object `obj`.
>
> 3) If a Class has both synchronized and non-synchronized methods, then any number of Threads can access the non-synchronized methods in any way they wish without having to wait for someone or something.

The Bottom line here is, Thread T2 doesn't need to wait for Thread T1 to complete its execution as it is trying to execute a non synchronized method. Hope This answer meets your expectations.

I see You have edited your question

> P.S. I have tried a test program already, and I see that my understanding is right. I am just wondering if there is any special scenario where this would not work as I explained to the interviewer.
>   **There is no such scenario. The above points should meet your question.**

Comment: Thanks Adil, I have the same understanding, not sure what answer was expected.
I edited my question, to inform that I tried this myself and found same result, and did not post a question without making any effort:)

Comment: No Problem, Happy to help. Upvote and select the answer if it helps :)

Comment: Accepted the answer, though could you please correct point2, it says T2 can, while it should say T2 can not